# Can boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(Int_Type) ever throw?

Tags: c++, boost

Is it possible that `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(Int_Type)` throw?  The only time I can think of where there will be no mem for string but can there be any other, more reasonable choices?

Comment: What is your definition of `boost<std::string>`?

Comment: -1 There's no such thing as `boost<std::string>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB end Ernest sorry I meant boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(Int_Type)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm#lexical_cast), `lexical_cast` can throw `bad_lexical_cast`. On top of that, as you already mentioned, there may be dynamic allocation, which can always cause a `bad_alloc` exception.

*Edit:* As for the particular situation `lexical_cast<std::string, int>`, it seems unlikely that any part along the chain could fail other than by allocation error, but the documentation doesn't (to my knowledge) guarantee that there won't be a "bad cast" exception.

Comment: How can bad_lexical_cast be thrown when converting int to string?

Comment: During the allocation of the memory for std::string?

Comment: @CharlesB: Perhaps it can't, you're right. Maybe if the underlying stream object fails for some reason... though the only way I can see *that* happening is again by allocation failure, which would simply bubble up as a `bad_alloc` exception...

Comment: I think a reasonable interpretation of "if the conversion is unsuccessful" would be, "if the source value cannot be represented in the destination type", in which case of course casts to `string` can't be unsuccessful. But another reasonable if very literal interpretation is to take the contrapositive: "if `bad_lexical_cast` is not thrown, the conversion is successful". That would *forbid* the function from throwing `bad_alloc`, it would have to catch it and throw `bad_lexical_cast` instead, which to me seems desperately unlikely. Might be a case for "use the source, Luke".

Comment: @Steve: [There you go](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/lexical_cast.hpp), I skimmed over it and I cannot say from a cursory glance.

Comment: @Matthieu: I went to the strenuous extent of searching the text for "catch", and there's nothing with `bad_alloc`. Which isn't to say there's no such catch hidden by a macro or in another file, but it cuts down the chances ;-)

Comment: @Steve: I was searching for the OP's question actually :) I don't know if under a bad moon you get a `bad_lexical_cast`, my initial thought was that if you configure your local with ` ` as a thousand separator it could play havoc with the stream conversion.